# Facing issue in installing emSigner Software, unable to port binding 1585 java

Tags: java-8

I am not able to start emsigner correctly.

getting below error
You’re almost there!

Just click on Start Service to start the emSigner service, if it is not started
automatically.

Note: If you want to stop the emSigner service running on your system then
just click on Stop Service.

Server configured on port 1585

Congrats! emSigner service started successfully.
some errors like port binding failed may not be assignable to a specific websocket